# Science fiction movies about alien creature

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I remember watching this movie in the 90s, so maybe it was made in 80s.
There was a creature or alien that travel inside the spaceship. And it kills men in the ship by sucking them through the drainage on the floor

Answer (score 1):

This does not feature an alien on a spaceship, but the most evocative scene of a man getting sucked down a sump drain and killed is from the generally not very good *Amityville:  It’s About Time*.